# typo3 extbase - variables available in layout

Tags: layout, typo3, extbase

Is there a way to assign variables available to the layout.html file? Just like I use something like

```
$this->view->assign('category', 20);
```

to make {category} available in my template files. But {category} is empty in my layout.html - how can I do this? Is that possible?

Comment: Please add some more context. Show me the controller and the action you try to add a variable to the view. Is your template file really named layout.html?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment this is not possible in the FLUID Framework. But you can make a kind of hook (a class between the fluid controllers and your extbase extension if your template is a part of an extension).

Also see this forge link:
[enter link description here](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/36410)